# how to create Docker image from ROS packges?

Tags: containers, dockerfile, ros, image-size, catkin

I want to create a Docker Image, which includes my ROS packages that I created in catkin_workspace.

I have already tried: create a container form official ros-kinetic-xenial. Create a catkin_workspace and send my packages into it. And create a image with docker commit.

Is there an another way to do that ? (to hold just Binaries and to make image smaller)

thanks

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look into using a Dockerfile to create the image. You can specify a base image and copy files from the build machine into the image. The Dockerfile snippet below configures an image to build off the ros-kinetic base image, then copies a local directory to the image.

```
FROM ros:kinetic
WORKDIR /docker/path/to/catkin_workspace
ADD /local/path/to/catkin_workspace /docker/path/to/catkin_workspace
```